# spring security app behind apache as reverse proxy

Tags: spring, tomcat

following problem I have:

I am developing a webapp with spring web mvc including spring security on a tomcat, locally lets name it: localhost:8080/myapp where I have secured lets say /user/** with hasRole('ROLE_USER')

Everything is running fine.

Now I have added an apache 2.4 as reverse proxy with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I have started both apache and tomcat, and I am then going on the URL localhost, its running correctly with showing me the url localhost/index which is my start. So far so good.

But when I log in, then he redirects in the successhandler for instance with the ROLE_USER to the url /user/index but then straightly goes again on index. The call of localhost/user/index also redirect to index, although the login was successful.

My config code looks like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/verify").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().formLogin.formLogin()
.successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
.loginProcessingUrl("/index")
.loginPage("/index")
.failureUrl("/index?error")
.permitAll()
```

What is the best practice to handle this issue?
It must be a spring security configuration but I would need help here. Thanks!

Expexcting is the behaviour that the url /user/index is secured and the user has access after a sucessful login to this url.